# Not responding during exeuting basic OpenMP (C) program

Tags: c, openmp, race-condition

I am currently new to OpenMp and trying to write a simple OpenMP-C matrix-vector multiplication program. On increasing the matrix size to 750x750 elements, my program stops responding and the window hangs. I would like to know if that is a limitation of my laptop or is it a data-race condition I am facing.

I am trying to define a matrix A and a vector u and put random elements (0-10). Then I am calculating the vector result b.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x_range = 50;
    int y_range = 50;
    int A[x_range][y_range];
    int u[y_range];
    int b[y_range];

    printf("Measuring time resolution %g\n", omp_get_wtick());
    printf("Parallel program start time %g\n", omp_get_wtime());
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(x_range)
    {
        int b_temp[y_range];
        for (int j = 0; j < y_range; j++)
        {
            b_temp[j] = 0;
        }
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < x_range; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y_range; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
            }
        }


        #pragma omp for
        for (int j = 0; j < y_range; j++)
        {
            {
                u[j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
            }
        }


        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < x_range; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < y_range; j++)
            {
                b_temp[i] = b_temp[i] + A[i][j]*u[j];
            }
        }

        #pragma omp critical
        for(int j = 0; j < y_range; j++)
        {
            b[j] = b[j] + b_temp[j];
        }
    }
    printf("parallel program end time %g\n", omp_get_wtime());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, operations you're performing cannot have data race conditions, because there's no RAW , WAR , WAW dependency. You can read more about them in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)).

Secondly, Your system is hanging because you're creating 750 threads as dictated by `x_range`

Comment: yeah, true. I tried setting num_threads = 10 and got the same problem. Can you suggest any other method I can look into?

Comment: Does it still hangs, if you change `#pragma omp critical` to `#pragma omp for` ?

Comment: yeah, I changed it and the window hangs. I tried static schedule with 10 threads, but same problem. #pragma omp for schedule (static, 10)

Comment: By an chance, are you doing all this is in virtual environment like VirtualBox or VMWare Player etc?